# Canvas scroll bar appears but doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a program to draw  charts. I emdbed a frame inside a canvas and then draw the charts inside the frame. There's a button embedded to the root. The button is pressed and the charts appear.

Although the  charts  appear, they seem to go out of the window (notice how i want 5 charts but this code produces only 3 on my machine). So I tried various methods of adding a horizontal scroll bar but to no avail. The scroll bar appears but never works.

Some solutions suggested that I shouldn't pack the frame and instead use canavas.create_window and pass the frame as window. But when I remove the frame.pack() line, the program just crashes. The program works only when i add frame.pack()

Below is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def on_configure(event=None):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def drawGraph(frame):

    for i in range(5):
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5,9,7,6,5,7,3,2,9,3,5])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, frame)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root)
frame=Frame(canvas)

xscrollbar=Scrollbar(canvas, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

button=Button(root, text='Go',command= lambda: drawGraph(frame))
button.pack()

canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)

xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
canvas.bind("<Configure>", on_configure)
frame.pack()
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You've posted way too much irrelevant code. Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. It would also help if the example relied on some hard-coded data rather than on a file you have on your machine.

Comment: If I knew where the problem was, I would have posted that part of the code alone. I don't know where the problem is, which is why i posted the entire code. I don't have hard coded data to show. I've tried my best to show  what the problem is through images for which I've shared the links. I'm new to this community and thus I'm not really good at posting questions. I've deleted a good bit of the code that was irrelevant. Please do help me now.

Comment: The whole point of the [mcve] is for you to find the root cause. For example, are any of those `Label` widgets really relevant to the question being asked? If you delete them does the problem persist? Do you really need radiobuttons and option menus, or can you hard-code the data? Do you really need matplotlib, or would a static image the same size as the generated image work?

Comment: I would like to tell you, that I do need matplotlib as the pie chart being generated varies based on what the user wishes to see. I posted all the widgets too, because I thought the problem maybe also due to me attaching them to the root. I've made all the changes, as you said. I thank you for pointing out the mistakes in my question. Please do tell me how to correct my code and get the desired result.

Comment: _you_ may need matplotlib, but does _this example_ need matplotlib? If the problem is with the scrollbar, the scrollbar probably doesn't care what generated the image.It might be that the example needs matplotlib, which is why a [mcve] is important. If you can illustrate that your code works fine with static images but fails when using matplotlib, that tells us the problem is somehow related to the combination of scrollbars and matplotlib. Or, if the problem persists with static images, we know it's not related to matplotlib.

Comment: The problem persists with or wtithout matplotlib. Please do see the images i attached for better clarity. My problem is the canvas where I draw the pie charts isn't big enough for all charts to fit. So i want a scroll bar to see all the charts because they're going out of the screen. But the scroll bar isn't working. I''l edit out the parts related to matplot lib also. Thanks for pointing it out, Please do tell me how to correct problem.

Comment: _"Please do tell me how to correct problem."_ - I will try, once there's a proper [mcve]. Right now it's impossible to duplicate the problem.

Comment: How much more do I need to refine my code? I removed nearly everything that you suggested and I deemed unnecessary. What remains of my code is only some functions to show parameters being passed for reference. I've also attached links to images which show what's exactly the problem. What else do you need to help me? I do understand what a minimal reproducible example means, but recreating the same problem will require lots of code again, which will bring you back to square one: Irrelevant code.

Comment: Please read this link: [mcve]. It needs to be as small as possible, it needs to run, and it needs to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I already read the link and I know you've stressed enough on it. But please do understand what I'm facing. I'm working on a dataset and drawing piecharts based on it. The pie charts are being drawn  based on the dataset. If you want to reproduce the exact, same problem, you would need the dataset and along with all manipulations I've done on it. I can't reproduce the exact same problem without the same or similar dataset based on which I'm drawing the charts. You need the charts to be draw in a certain way to reproduce the exact same problem.

Comment: We need to reproduce the exact _problem_, not your exact code. The _problem_ is that the scrollbar isn't working. You need to start from scratch and create a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you have. We don't care about the dataset if the problem is about scrolling. Scrolling doesn't care where the data came from. You said earlier that the problem exists with or without matplotlib, so I don't understand why you think you have to use matplotlib to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You can put whatever code you want, obviously, I'm just trying to give advice about how to improve your chances of getting help. You'll likely not find many people willing to wade through hundreds of lines of code, install packages they don't have, or to work through a bunch of mock code that won't actually run. It's your job to make the question as simple and as clear to understand as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I found a way to reproduce the same problem with 50 lines of code. Please do look at at now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have matplotlib on my machine. You said earlier the problem was there with or without matplotlib. This example is definitely better, though.

Comment: Yes. How do you suggest I modify my code so that you can help me?

Comment: The problem occurs whenever I display something that goes out of screen (whether it be an image or a graph from matplotlib). If you don't have matplotlib, an image can also do the same job. If i replace the graphs draw with images, the problem of the scrollbar not getting active, still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake i was doing. I didn't set the anchor in create_window. So the answer goes as follows (add it after canvas.pack()):

```
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw') #or any other suitable anchor
```

Also add:

```
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Also remove the following line:

```
frame.pack()
```

The code works now.